# Missed Canada Biometric Submission Deadline

Tags: canada, tourist-visas, biometric-passports

My biometric collection expiry was set for 18th November. Unfortunately, between 18th October and 30th October, I was unable to secure a leave of absence from my office due to extensive travel commitments and the ongoing restructuring and layoffs within the company.

Subsequently, from 30th October to 9th November, I faced the additional challenge of contracting COVID-19. As of today(9th of November),  the earliest available date is 24th November.

Consequently, I have scheduled my biometrics appointment for the 24th of November, but this lies past my expiry date.

I've already submitted the web form for inquiry, but would it suffice?

Comment: This is a question we cannot answer. You have to contact the office to which you submitted the application. Or wait for their response.